# Can we download video and play it with flutter without add it into asset?

Tags: flutter

I want to download video with flutter (maybe use dio package), and play it in the screen automatic. There is a way to do that?

I have searched it but feel like it only can play a video have added to asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this one [Flutter Video Player](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video)

The `VideoPlayerController` offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files, or the internet.

Comment: @hoangquyy if it works, accept the answer so that it can help others also

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video and can download that to app directory and get the path from there and then play using a video player.don't need to play it from assets.